# Using String Interpolation macro in Clojure (<<)

Tags: clojure, interpolation, string-interpolation

Just getting started with clojure.  I'm using [leiningen](https://github.com/technomancy/leiningen) and can't figure out why my importing of the `<<` macro doesn't seem to be working

**project.clj**

```
(defproject myapp "0.1"
  :description "Clojure learning sandbox"
  :main myapp.core
  :dependencies [[org.clojure/clojure "1.4.0"]
                 [org.clojure/core.incubator "0.1.2" ]])
```

**core.clj**

```
(ns clojure-shuffle
  (:require [clojure.core.incubator :refer [<<]]))

(defn -main [& args]
  (println (<< "The sum is: ~(reduce + (map read-string args))")))
```

and when i do a `lein run 3 7 2` I expect

```
The sum is: 12
```

However I get this (followed by a large stacktrace):

```
 Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalAccessError: << does not exist
```

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Perhaps you need to use the **[clojure.core.strint](https://github.com/clojure/core.incubator/blob/28110f5c87af399b3afca8f295030dda732439f6/src/main/clojure/clojure/core/strint.clj#L15-L18)** namespace?

Comment: This seems to be depricated (https://github.com/richhickey/clojure-contrib) in favor of this (https://github.com/clojure/core.incubator) since 1.4 I believe.

Comment: ahhh... that's confusing, but I see now